# Sum of lists for each element of list1 with all in list2

Tags: python

I want make script that reads lines from file, than takes slices from each line, combines all slices from 1 line with all slices from 2 line, then combines all slices from previous step with 3rd line.

For example, we have

```
Stackoverflow (4)
python (3)
question (3)
```

I get first list with slices of (number) letters.

```
lst = ['Stac', 'tack', 'acko', 'ckov', 'kove', 'over', 'verf', 'erfl', 'rflo', 'flow']
```

Then i need to combine it with second list:

```
lst = ['pyt', 'yth', 'tho', 'hon']
```

Desired output:

```
finallist = ['Stacpyt', 'tackpyt', 'ackopyt', 'ckovpyt', 'kovepyt', 'overpyt', 'verfpyt', 'erflpyt', 'rflopyt', 'flowpyt' 'Stacyth', 'tackyth', 'ackoyth', 'ckovyth', 'koveyth', 'overyth', 'verfyth', 'erflyth', 'rfloyth', 'flowyth', ..... ,  'erflhon', 'rflohon', 'flowhon']
```

then with 3rd list:

```
lst = ['que', 'ues', 'est', 'sti', 'tio', 'ion']

finallist = ['Stacpytque', 'tackpytque', 'ackopytque', 'ckovpytque', 'kovepytque', 'overpytque', 'verfpytque', 'erflpytque', 'rflopytque', .... 'erflhonion', 'rflohonion', 'flowhonion']
```

I stuck at point where I need to make finallist with combined results.

I am trying pieces of code like this, but its wrong:

```
for i in lst:
    for y in finallist:
        finallist.append(i + y)
```

So if finallist is empty - it should copy lst in first loop iteration, and if finallist is not empty it should combine each element with lst and so on.

Comment: The 4/3/3 numbers are also in the file? Is your example exactly how your file looks like?

Comment: Yes, numbers in file too. It stands for length of slice for list.

If it was Stackoverflow (12). Script should make ["Stackoverflo", "tackoverflow"]. 

To be honest, i didnt learn how to filter string to get int, so i skipped it for now and made a variable.

Comment: File can contain any number of strings, not just 3. Sorry for misunderstanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [`re.match()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.match) in order to get the word and the integer value from your file.

Then, I compute all the sliced subwords and add them to a list, which is then added to a global list.

Finally, I compute all the possibilties you are looking for thank to [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) which behaves like a nested for-loop.

Then, [`.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the tuples obtained and you get the final list you wanted.

```
from itertools import product
from re import match

the_lists = []

with open("filename.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        m = match(r'(.*) \((\d+)\)', line)
        word = m.group(1)
        num = int(m.group(2))
        the_list = [word[i:i+num] for i in range(len(word) - num + 1)]
        the_lists.append(the_list)

combinaisons = product(*the_lists)

final_list = ["".join(c) for c in combinaisons]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what i was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**ittertools**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)

```
import itertools
list1 = ['Stac', 'tack', 'acko', 'ckov', 'kove', 'over', 'verf', 'erfl', 'rflo', 'flow']
list2 = ['pyt', 'yth', 'tho', 'hon']
list3 = ['que', 'ues', 'est', 'sti', 'tio', 'ion']

final_list = list(itertools.product(list(itertools.product(list1,list2)),list3))
```

This will give you all combinations, then you can just join all of them to get your string.

Comment: Number of lists are equal to number of strings. It can be more than 3. So i made a loop that makes list from every line. And iinside of this loop i want to make another one that will combine finallist (it is empty on count 0) with current list

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't read that part. In that case make *for loop* with list which has all items and then use itertools.

Comment: i used iter in loop `alllst = finallist(itertools.product(finallist,templist))` and i didnt get desired ouput. i get `[(('Stac', 'pyt'), 'que'), (('Stac', 'pyt'), 'ues'), (('Stac', 'pyt'), 'est'), (('Stac', 'pyt'), 'sti'), (('Stac', 'pyt'), 'tio'), (('Stac', 'pyt'), 'ion'), (('Stac', 'yth'), 'que'), (('Stac', 'yth'), 'ues')` 

Items are not together.

And second:
if finallist is empty at beggining. I get empty list in end. Is only way to solve it to make `if count == 1: finallist = templist` in loop ???

Comment: You might need to use "newlist = list2 + list2" before using it in itertools for net time. It will flatten two lists (which you are getting in your code) into one single list.

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

def combine(lst):
    result = list(itertools.product(*lst))
    result = [''.join(item) for item in result]
    return result

list1 = ['Stac', 'tack', 'acko', 'ckov', 'kove', 'over', 'verf', 'erfl', 'rflo', 'flow']
list2 = ['pyt', 'yth', 'tho', 'hon']
list3 = ['que', 'ues', 'est', 'sti', 'tio', 'ion']

lst = [list1, list2, list3]  # append more list to lst, then pass lst to combination
print combine(lst)
```

Append all of the candidate lists to `lst`, and the `combine()` function will generate all kinds of combinations and then returns the result as a list.